# What script will return the required data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am using this script to try and retrieve rows from the following table that meet this criteria, but I don't think it's working as it should.
For instance for CARE_ID 3907, the row for EVENT_ID 3593 is being returned and I believe this should be 3591.
The script has to fairly old school to be compatible with SQL2000.

```
 SELECT nbe.CARE_ID, nbe.EVENT_DATE, nbe.EVENT_ID, nbe.EVENT_TYPE
   FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS nbe
        JOIN
            (SELECT CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE, MAX(EVENT_DATE) as maxx
               FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
              GROUP BY CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE
             HAVING EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
            ) tmax
            ON nbe.CARE_ID = tmax.CARE_ID AND nbe.EVENT_DATE = tmax.maxx
  WHERE nbe.EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
    AND EVENT_DATE <= 
        (SELECT MIN(EVENT_DATE)
           FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
          WHERE CARE_ID = nbe.CARE_ID
            AND EVENT_TYPE IN ('BR','CH','SU', 'TE'))

UNION ALL

 SELECT t.CARE_ID, t.EVENT_DATE, MAX(t.EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_ID, t.EVENT_TYPE
   FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS t
        JOIN 
            (SELECT CARE_ID, MAX(EVENT_DATE) as maxx, EVENT_TYPE
               FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
              GROUP BY CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE
             HAVING EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
            ) tmax
            ON t.CARE_ID = tmax.CARE_ID AND t.EVENT_DATE = tmax.maxx
  GROUP BY t.CARE_ID, t.EVENT_DATE, t.EVENT_TYPE
 HAVING t.EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
    AND t.CARE_ID NOT IN
        (SELECT CARE_ID
           FROM
                (SELECT nbe.CARE_ID, nbe.EVENT_DATE, MAX(nbe.EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_ID,
                        nbe.EVENT_TYPE
                   FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS nbe
                        JOIN
                            (SELECT CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE, MAX(EVENT_DATE) as maxx
                               FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
                              GROUP BY CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE
                             HAVING EVENT_TYPE = 'CP') tmax
                            ON nbe.CARE_ID = tmax.CARE_ID AND nbe.EVENT_DATE = tmax.maxx
                  GROUP BY nbe.CARE_ID, nbe.EVENT_DATE, nbe.EVENT_TYPE
                 HAVING nbe.EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
                    AND EVENT_DATE <=
                        (SELECT MIN(EVENT_DATE)
                           FROM vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
                          WHERE CARE_ID = nbe.CARE_ID
                            AND EVENT_TYPE IN ('BR','CH','SU','TE'))
                )a
        )
```

Comments

```
--For each CARE_ID with at least one EVENT_TYPE of 'CP' before an 
--EVENT_TYPE of 'BR', 'CH', 'SU', 'TE' return the most recent instance 
--of 'CP' - i.e. the last CP before the first 'BR', 'CH', 'SU' or 'TE' 
--(the tie breaker for 'CP' is MAX(EVENT_ID) and MIN(EVENT_ID) 
--for 'BR', 'CH', 'SU' or 'TE')

--For each CARE_ID with at least one EVENT_TYPE of 'CP' 
--that isn't included above return the most recent 'CP' 
--(the tie breaker for 'CP' is MAX(EVENT_ID))
```

Output

```
CARE_ID EVENT_ID    EVENT_DATE          EVENT_TYPE
3       117         09/04/2010 00:00    CP
3       104         11/04/2010 00:00    CH
3       190         16/04/2010 00:00    SU
3       16          12/07/2010 00:00    BR
3       17          13/07/2010 00:00    BR
3       18          13/07/2010 00:00    BR
78      11          27/07/2009 00:00    CH
78      9           28/07/2009 00:00    TE
78      706         08/12/2010 00:00    CP
78      707         09/12/2010 00:00    CP
107     93          23/02/2010 00:00    CP
107     1474        21/09/2012 00:00    SU
206     84          28/07/2009 00:00    CP
206     85          21/08/2009 00:00    CP
364     1122        26/01/2011 00:00    CP
364     1136        18/02/2011 00:00    CP
364     569         19/02/2011 00:00    SU
364     774         23/08/2012 00:00    CH
367     151         21/06/2010 00:00    CP
367     247         01/07/2010 00:00    SU
369     248         26/07/2010 00:00    SU
369     152         27/07/2010 00:00    CP
369     117         28/07/2010 00:00    CH
380     277         08/07/2011 00:00    TE
481     63          07/09/2010 00:00    TE
481     194         07/09/2010 00:00    CP
481     289         07/09/2010 00:00    SU
1535    924         11/01/2011 00:00    CP
1536    925         11/01/2011 00:00    CP
1565    979         09/01/2011 00:00    CP
1623    531         27/01/2011 00:00    SU
1661    216         25/01/2011 00:00    CH
1661    217         25/01/2011 00:00    CH
1661    1046        25/01/2011 00:00    CP
1661    95          01/02/2011 00:00    TE
1661    218         01/02/2011 00:00    CH
1662    220         25/01/2011 00:00    CH
1662    1047        25/01/2011 00:00    CP
1662    221         01/02/2011 00:00    CH
1663    97          25/01/2011 00:00    TE
1663    1048        25/01/2011 00:00    CP
1663    98          01/02/2011 00:00    TE
1663    223         01/02/2011 00:00    CH
1665    1049        25/01/2011 00:00    CP
1666    100         23/01/2011 00:00    TE
1666    1050        23/01/2011 00:00    CP
1666    225         01/02/2011 00:00    CH
1781    1868        04/10/2010 00:00    CP
1781    1869        04/10/2010 00:00    CP
1781    1870        04/10/2010 00:00    CP
1781    1052        10/02/2011 00:00    SU
1781    1867        25/03/2011 00:00    CP
1781    2103        20/01/2014 00:00    CP
1903    1551        02/06/2011 00:00    CP
1903    1552        16/07/2011 00:00    CP
2187    1475        20/01/2011 00:00    CP
2187    803         29/01/2011 00:00    SU
2294    66          12/06/2011 00:00    BR
2294    1697        16/07/2011 00:00    CP
2294    1698        17/07/2011 00:00    CP
3907    3591        05/01/2014 00:00    CP
3907    945         09/01/2014 00:00    CH
3907    1821        13/01/2014 00:00    SU
3907    3592        14/01/2014 00:00    CP
3907    3593        14/01/2014 00:00    CP
```

Comment: This query is too big to nail the error from the first glance, you'll likely end up with no answer. Perhaps you should simplify the query and dataset to produce the result similar to yours.

Comment: Sorry, but that is far too complex for me to understand just from reading it.  Can you replicate using http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

My **first comment** is to **get off SQL Server 2000**.  The unleash of SQL Server 2014 was 1 month ago.  However, as a DBA I have worked with business lines that did not plan for the future.  They wanted to use the software until it was unsupportable.

My **second comment** is to **use temp tables to simply the query**.  While you might not be able to inject the final result back into the software, it will leave trace tables around that can used for investigation and debuggin.

Do not forget that this code can be wrapped in a stored procedure that returns a result set.  If it is a report, just change the calling code.

So here is the re-write that is a-lot simpler than above.

The max and min queries have their own tables.  I did notice that the min event type criteria was not the same as the max.

I added back event type on the grouping.  This can be eliminated in the sub-query with another MIN() call.  However, there is something to be said for consistency.

```
--
-- Create temp table for max event date
--

SELECT 
    CARE_ID, 
    EVENT_TYPE, 
    MAX(EVENT_DATE) as maxx
INTO
    #tmax
FROM 
    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
GROUP BY 
    CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE
HAVING 
    EVENT_TYPE = 'CP'
GO


--
-- Create temp table for min event date
--

SELECT 
    CARE_ID, 
    EVENT_TYPE, 
    MIN(EVENT_DATE) as minn
INTO
    #tmin
FROM 
    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS
GROUP BY 
    CARE_ID, EVENT_TYPE
HAVING 
    EVENT_TYPE IN ('BR','CH','SU', 'TE')
GO
```

The actual core query is now cleaner.  I removed the grouping from the last sub query on the union all since you only need the CARE ID's.

```
--
-- Actual query
-- 

SELECT  
    nbe.CARE_ID, 
    nbe.EVENT_DATE, 
    nbe.EVENT_ID, 
    nbe.EVENT_TYPE
FROM    
    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS nbe
JOIN 
    #tmax 
ON 
    nbe.CARE_ID = #tmax.CARE_ID AND 
    nbe.EVENT_DATE = #tmax.maxx
WHERE 
    nbe.EVENT_TYPE = 'CP' AND 
    EVENT_DATE <= 
    (SELECT MIN(#tmin.minn) FROM #tmin WHERE #tmin.CARE_ID = nbe.CARE_ID)


UNION ALL


SELECT  
    t.CARE_ID, 
    t.EVENT_DATE, 
    MAX(t.EVENT_ID) AS EVENT_ID, 
    t.EVENT_TYPE
FROM    
    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS t 
JOIN 
    #tmax 
ON 
    nbe.CARE_ID = #tmax.CARE_ID AND 
    nbe.EVENT_DATE = #tmax.maxx
GROUP BY 
    t.CARE_ID, 
    t.EVENT_DATE, 
    t.EVENT_TYPE
HAVING
    t.EVENT_TYPE = 'CP' AND
    t.CARE_ID NOT IN
(
SELECT 
    DISTINCT CARE_ID 
FROM    
    vwNBOCAP_BASE_EVENTS nbe
JOIN  
    #tmax
ON 
    nbe.CARE_ID = #tmax.CARE_ID 
    AND nbe.EVENT_DATE = #tmax.maxx
WHERE
    nbe.EVENT_TYPE = 'CP' AND 
    EVENT_DATE <= 
    (SELECT MIN(#tmin.minn) FROM #tmin WHERE #tmin.CARE_ID = nbe.CARE_ID)
)
```

Again, I have no clue about your business logic;  However, the cleaned up version should be easier to debug.

I choose to respond to this question since I am speaking tonight at the Maine, USA - PASS SQL Server User Group on Effective Use of Temporary Tables.

This question fits right into my topic.,

Best of luck, the crafty dba.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I work for an organisation that supplies an application and database to customers who still work with Enterprise Manager and SQL2000. Thankfully there are only two left and they are on notice. I am all for temp tables, as long as they are not too expensive a hit on the database. I had corrected some pseudonyms in your script to get it to run but it is not returning the expected data. CARE_ID 3907 is still returning EVENT_ID 3593 which is the most recent EVENT_ID and not the most recent EVENT_ID before the first instance of 'BR','CH','SU' or 'TE'

Comment: Hi Paul, the only hit from this is space in tempdb.  Just make sure you have at least 4 data files and say 1 GB each.  I usually have at least a 256 MB log file.  The default (from Model) is like 8 mb data and 1 mb log.  Good luck - J